# which version of angular is this template?

Tags: angular, templates, version, angular5

i have installed an angular template but i don't know with which version of angular is this template developed , 
so here is the content of the file package.json

```
           {
           "name": "@coreui/coreui-free-angular-admin-template",
           "version": "2.0.0-beta.0",
           "description": "CoreUI Free Angular 2+ Admin Template",
           "author": "Łukasz Holeczek",
           "homepage": "https://coreui.io/angular",
           "copyright": "Copyright 2018 creativeLabs Łukasz Holeczek",
           "license": "MIT",
           "scripts": {

      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "ng serve",
      "build": "ng build --prod",
      "test": "ng test",
      "lint": "ng lint",
      "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
            "private": true,


"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.9",
    "@coreui/angular": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "chart.js": "2.7.2",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "flag-icon-css": "3.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "2.22.0",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "5.3.5",
    "rxjs": "5.5.8",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "9.6.2",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.9.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.3.1",
    "ts-node": "4.1.0",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 8.9.4",
    "npm": ">= 5.6.0"
  }
}
```

while using ng serve on this template i get this warning :

```
     @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.9 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0' but 2.7.2 was found instead.
Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.

Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.

    npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0'

To disable this warning run "ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".
```

i want to work with Angular5/4 template

PS : if you need other information please add it in a comment , thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your package.json file your app is using version 5.2.9 of angular.  That type script message is because you're using a latter version of typescript than the version of angular you're using was built with.  If you change this

"typescript": "2.7.2"

To

"typescript": "2.6"

You'll get rid of that warning.

Comment: thank you for your help , which line you used to decide that it's 5.2.9 ? :)

Comment: "@angular/core": "5.2.9"...  But if you're generating apps work the cli the angular dependencies will all be the same version number ( except the cli number, that will be different)

Comment: okey the most important thing for me now is that this template uses the anguar 5 version right? thank you